SSRS toggle filter based on a parameter value
I am using Power Bi report builder that is running off a Power Bi data model so I am quite limited to putting all this fixes in a Stored Proc.
I have the following req :-
If @Param1 = Y then School no. = @No.
if @Param1 = N then Trust No. = @No.
How best to implement this approach please?
I have tried implementing this using SSRS filter expression using existing examples from my google search but I am really stuck!
